# How can I apply interaction term with linear predictors in mgcv package

Tags: r, glm, gam, mgcv

I have a question about using interaction term in `mgcv` package with 2 linear predictor.

I wrote the code to fit interaction between `x1` and `x2`,

`mgcv::gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + ti(x1, x2, k = 3), method = "REML", data = DATA)`

but I'm really not sure this is correct way to using `ti` function in `mgcv`.

Should I use different method (like `glm`?) to do this work?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a non-linear interaction, you have two choices:

```r
gam(y ~ te(x1, x2), method = "REML", data = DATA)
```

or

```r
gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + ti(x1, x2), method = "REML", data = DATA)
```

In the first model, the main effects and interactions are bound up in the one two-dimensional function `te(x1,x2)`.

In the second model, because `ti(x1, x2)` will exclude the main *smooth* effects or the marginal terms (`x1`, `x2`), you should also include the main
smooth effects of these terms too using `s()`.

With your formulation, you would not get any non-linear main effects, only linear main effects and a non-linear pure-interaction, which is likely not what you want.

Here's an example:

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")
library("ggplot2")
library("patchwork")

set.seed(1)
df2 <- data_sim(2, n = 1000, dist = "normal", scale = 1, seed = 2)

m1 <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = 5) + s(z, k = 5) + ti(x, z, k = 5),
          data = df2,
          method = "REML")
m2 <- gam(y ~ x + z + ti(x, z, k = 5),
          data = df2
          method = "REML")

pl <- plot_layout(nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
p1 <- draw(m1) + pl
p2 <- draw(m2, parametric = TRUE) + pl

p1 - p2 + plot_layout(nrow = 2)
```

which produces

[image]

Notice how in this case, you would be missing the non-linear in the marginal smooths/terms, which is not accounted for in the `ti()` term, because it has no marginal main effects (the `ti()` smooths are the same across both models).

If you just want to fit a linear "main effects" and their linear interaction, just use the formula as you would with `glm()`:

```r
gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, ....)
```

Note that the term "linear predictor" refers to the entire model (in the case), or more specifically the entire formula on the RHS of `~`.

Comment: You can also technically achieve the interaction you specify like so right? `gam(y ~ ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1, x2), method = "REML", data = DATA)`. I've seen [on the smooth terms page that both are used](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html), but I find that fairly confusing.

Comment: You can do that @ShawnHemelstrand but I would suggest that using `s()` is much clearer about the intention of the code/model. And also, at some point Simon Wood, developer of {mgcv} indicated that he might remove the ability for tensor product smooth to work for a single variable, i.e. he thought about forcing `s()` for univariate terms.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I fit a model recently with the `s()` term but then saw the `ti()` term used in another article by Baayen et al., 2017, so I switched to that after and got weirdly similar results (which makes sense now). I think to be safe, your idea of using `s()` stands more to reason, so I will probably just use that from now on. Anyways, appreciate your insight, that clears up my confusion.